# Problems typing controllers on node/express application

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm coding my first Node/Express API and I decide to use Typescript ( I already use TS a bit in a React project in my work ).

I have the following controller:

```ts
import { Request, Response } from "express";

const syncWallet = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  // awaits everywhere
  res.status(204)
};
```

For controllers/routes I created the following interfaces in `/src/index.d.ts`:

```ts
interface Controller {
  (
    req: Express.Request,
    res: Express.Response,
    next?: Express.NextFunction
  ): Promise<void> | void;
}

interface Route{
  path: string;
  method: string;
  controller: Controller;
}
```

So in `routes.ts` file I'm exporting an array of type `Array<Route>` because im using this function

```ts
import { Router } from "express";

export const applyRoutes = (routes: Array<Route>, router: Router) => {
  for (const route of routes) {
    const { method, path, controller } = route;
    (router as any)[method](path, controller);
  }
};
```

With this `Route` type I can organize my project in a way similar to Django ( url + views ).

So, in my `main.ts` file a have:

```ts
import http from "http";
import express from "express";
import errorHandlers from "./middlewares/errorHandler";
import routes from "./routes";
import {applyRoutes} from "./routes/handlers"
import * as bodyParser from 'body-parser'


const router = express();
router.use(bodyParser.json())
applyRoutes(routes, router);

const { PORT = 3000 } = process.env;
const server = http.createServer(router);

server.listen(PORT, () =>
  console.log(`Server is running http://localhost:${PORT}...`)
);
```

But I'm recieving the following error:

```
src/main.ts(22,13): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ path: string; method: string; controller: (req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>, res: Response<any>) => Promise<void>; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Route[]'.
  Type '{ path: string; method: string; controller: (req: Request, res: Response) => Promise<void>; }' is not assignable to type 'Route'.
    Types of property 'controller' are incompatible.
      Type '(req: Request, res: Response) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'Controller'.
        Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
          Type 'Request' is missing the following properties from type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>': get, header, accepts, acceptsCharsets, and 77 more.
```

Any hint of what I'm missing ?

Comment: typescript.. turning 1 line into 20+ `const routes = [{ path: "/test", method: "GET", controller: async (req, res) => res.status(204) }];
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was just a wrong use of async/await and a confusion with `http.Request` type and `Express.Request` type.